# Segment characters from license plate image according to regions with same height

Tags: python, opencv

I have (for example) the following license plate image: [image]

And I want to segment the characters. The code I have so far consists of me using `cv2.MSER` to detect regions in the image. Afterwards I create bounding rectangles for each of the contours and create a dictionary according to height of the bounding boxes (characters). Then I get a dictionary key with the biggest number of items, this is an assumption, as there should not be anything else in the image other than the characters that are clearly visible and of the same height (relatively). The values of the key are x,y coordinates and width and height parameters of the bounding box. Afterwards, I sort the items of this dict key according to the x value, so that they are ordered as in the license plate image from left to right. Then I loop through the list in reverse order to remove duplicates (based on Euclidean distance I believe). What I want to know if there is any step of this process that could be improved upon, or if there is a defect in the thinking process. Code for show:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('path_to_img', 0)
mser = cv2.MSER_create()      
regions = mser.detectRegions(img)[0]
h_dict = {}    # group contours according to height
for cnt in regions:
  x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
  if h in h_dict:
    if (x,y,w,h) not in h_dict[h]:
      h_dict[h].append((x,y,w,h))
    else:
      continue
  else:
    h_dict[h] = [(x,y,w,h)]

longest_key = max(h_dict, key=lambda x: len(h_dict[x]))
sorted_longest = sorted(h_dict[longest_key], key=lambda x: [x][0])  # order according to x coordinate

# remove duplicates    
for i, val in reversed(list(enumerate(sorted_longest))):
  for j, val2 in reversed(list(enumerate(sorted_longest))):
    if j > i:
      result_dist = np.linalg.norm(np.asarray(val) - np.asarray(val2))
      if result_dist < 2:
        del sorted_longest[j]
```

Resulting image horizontally stacked: [image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the logic of using the height as a key... Are you saying that all letters and numbers to be extracted are exactly the same height in pixels? That cannot always be true, can it? Even the slightest bit of noise or geometric distortion will make one character a pixel taller than its neighbor.

Comment: I have thought about pooling contours of "roughly" the same height together, e.g. of height 39-43 as height 41.